# Storing ICO tokens in contract address instead of owner address

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, ico

In most of the ICOs,initially all tokens are transferred to  owner address instead of being handled at the 
contract address.Why?.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular reason. Some owners may want the possibility to manually assign tokens. But that can also be accomplished with a owner only function in the contract.

One important difference is that when the tokens are not assigned to the contract then you will have to call `approve()` and the contract have to call `transferFrom()` to assign tokens, which has a small increment in gas usage.

Comment: If that is the case, how  trust is enabled ? bcos I trust only the smart contract not any individual account address(Even owner)

Comment: Detailed question is here :https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69177/in-icos-why-initial-supply-total-supply-tokens-are-transferred-to-owner-address

Comment: @Jerrin When you buy an ICO you are trusting that they will fulfill on they promise. It used to be that they publish a whitepaper explaining how many tokens will be distributed, and to whom.